# How to change the border color of an image frequently by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the border color of an image frequently by Javascript?

```
<img id="me" width=auto height=auto border=3 style="border-color: red green yellow blue;" src="myimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "frequently"? When does it have to change? What have you tried?

Comment: Frequently means changing color in a second interval.

Comment: Is there anything you tried? Can you share it? As you are new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

With this you can change the border every set interval from what you are saying, all you have to do is modify the `100` in the `setTimeout` method to any millesecond time.

And anytime you want to change the color set `globalColor` equal to a hexidecimal color.  This will every 100ms or what ever you change it to set the border to `globalColor`.

```js
var globalColor;

function setColor(color) {
  img1.style.borderColor = "#" + color;
}

var imageTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  setColor(globalColor);
}, 100);
```

```css
img#img1 {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/250x250" alt="image1" id="img1">
```